# super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

Tags: android

Hy I am developing an Android Application that contains one host activity with multiple fragments. I was using onActivityResult() method in my host Activity as well as in my fragments.

In host Activity

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode)
    {
    }
}
```

In fragment

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);        
     switch (requestCode)
    {
    }
}
```

When I started activityForResult from fragment then fragment's onActivityResult was not getting called.
I was doing it like this

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),REQUEST_CODE);
```

I solved my problem when I added this line to my host activity's result method
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode)
    {
    }
}
```

Now onActivityResult() of my fragment is getting call. 
I want to know what this line super.onActivityResult() actually do when I added it in Activities onResult method ? in which order the onActivityResult() gets call, when activity has multiple fragments.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment

Comment: If you want to user host activity's onActivityResult then you have to start startActivityForResult() like this --> getActivity().startActivityForResult(....)

Comment: No I dont want to use result method of host activity . I have independent result method in fragment that was not getting call and when i added super.onActivityResult() in result method of host activity then result method of fragment start working. I want to know why this happened.

Comment: super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); this will call Main Frgament class "onActivityResult" method.

     
     * Receive the result from a previous call to
     * {@link #startActivityForResult(Intent, int)}.  This follows the
     * related Activity API as described there in
     * {@link Activity#onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)}.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know what this line super.onActivityResult()

in your case, it calls the `onActivityResult` of `FragmentActivity`. There Android checks if there is a `Fragment` that should get its onActivityResult called.

> in which order the onActivityResult() gets call, when activity has
>   multiple fragments

The hosting `Activity` first and, eventually, the `Fragment` that called `startActivityForResult`.

For a deeper insight on the topic, have a look to `FragmentActiviy#onActivityResult`